# MYSQL average function outputs .0000

Tags: mysql, average

I have this simple column named "price" and want to get the average number of all the rows. I have this code:

> $avg = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(price) FROM books WHERE
>   author='$postname'");
>
> $avgprice = mysql_fetch_assoc($avg);

When I go for the output:

```
<?php echo $avgprice['AVG(price)'] ?>
```

It gives me 250.0000 and not 250 which is the actual number. Why do i get these 4 decimals after the output?

Comment: check the datatype of your column `price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how AVG function works, it return a number with 4 decimals.  If you want to round it try this:

```
    $avg = mysql_query("SELECT ROUND( AVG(price) ) as avg FROM books WHERE author='$postname'");

    $avgprice = mysql_fetch_assoc($avg);

<?php echo $avgprice['avg'] ?>
```